# leaflet setLatLngs function throws the error: "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I try to set the points of polyline in leaflet.
the function 'setLatLngs' throws an error: "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

```
    let points = link._path;
    ...change the points
    link.setLatLngs(points);

//point value is: 
[
  "M",
  [55.770483, 37.715871],
  "Q",
  [55.764653, 37.706289],
  [55.765565, 37.695111],
  "Q",
  [55.7391573, 37.6762553],
  [55.7288665, 37.6454815]
];
```

when I try to add new polyline with the same values, and remove the prev, it works well:

```
let line = L.polyline.antPath(
             points,
             link.options);
line.addTo(map);
link.remove();
```

**link.options contains: "use: L.curve" does 'setLatlngs' function ignore it? 
if true, how can I use it?**

Comment: I don't know the library that you are using, but `apply` is a method callable on functions. This means that, maybe, `setLatLngs` may expect a function as second parameter. Since when you don't pass a parameter, it's like you're passing `undefined`

Comment: thanks!  but 'setLatLngs' wants to get just this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is one more situation where you should be encouraged to read the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference) thoroughly.

The [`L.Polyline` constructor](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline) expects an array of [`L.LatLng`s](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlng) (or `L.LatLng`-like accepted data structures, [as described](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlng)). The same goes for the [`setLatLngs` method of `L.Polyline`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline-setlatlngs).

But instead of an array of `LatLng`s, you're passing a modified copy of the (undocumented, unsupported, internal) `_path` property, which should be an instance of [`SVGPathElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement) (note the `M` and `Q`s, and how they relate to [drawing SVG paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)). I'm even surprised you can get a array/string representation of a `SVGPathElement`. And you might even not have a `_path` property if you're using [`L.Canvas`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#canvas) instead of [`L.SVG`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#svg) as the vector renderer.

Don't do that. Don't use undocumented stuff (unless you're willing to dig down into the source code).

Instead, use the [`getLatLngs()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline-getlatlngs), and be mindful of the input and output of your function calls.